# Pandas: List-like indexing for .loc[...]

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I think I'm missing something very simple, but I'm trying to use list-like indexing with `.loc[...]` to select all but the last row in a dataframe.

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'b':[6,7,8,9,0]
    })
```

**Attempted code:**

```
df.loc[:-1, 'a'] = df.loc[:-1, 'b']
```

But `df.loc[:-1, 'a']` yields: `Series([], Name: a, dtype: int64)` and not that series up until the last row.

**Desired result:**

```
   a  b
0  6  6
1  7  7
2  8  8
3  9  9
4  5  0
```

**Working, but hacky code:**

```
df.loc[:df.shape[0] - 2, 'a'] = df.loc[:df.shape[0] - 1, 'b']
```

My actual code is more complex and relies on this code, so I don't want to completely reinvent the wheel to get to the desired result, I guess I was just wondering if there's a simple way to find rows similar to native python's `l[:-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to mix label-based indexing with integer indexing/slicing. You can't use `loc` for that, which is for label-*loc*ation based indexing.

Pandas currently provides `ix` for mixing label and integer based indexing. But that will be deprecated in a future version.

One thing you can do is grab the labels from the index using using integer-based slicing on the *index*:

```
In [20]: df.loc[df.index[:-1], 'a']
Out[20]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

So your example would be:

```
In [22]: df.loc[df.index[:-1], 'a'] = df.loc[df.index[:-1], 'b']

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   a  b
0  6  6
1  7  7
2  8  8
3  9  9
4  5  0

In [24]:
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  That looks like it's the cleanest it's going to get. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use .iloc for index slicing with :-1.

```
df.iloc[:-1,df.columns.get_loc('a')] = df.iloc[:-1,df.columns.get_loc('b')]
```

Otherwise with, .loc you are looking up a label of ':-1' is returning no rows hence the [] Series you are getting returned.  By using df.columns.get_loc you are returning the column index of the row labelled 'a' and 'b'.

```
Output:

   a  b
0  6  6
1  7  7
2  8  8
3  9  9
4  5  0
```

Comment: Hmmm, ok.  So that's basically the inverse of my working `.loc[...]` version.  I guess my real question is whether a more simple method is available.  But it sounds like not.  I'm going to hold off on accepting this for a bit, but thanks for the insight.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.  I hope someone has a better solution.